# Equality of covariance implies transformationis is linear. Is it true?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose, for two positive random variable $X$ and $Y$, and non-negative function $g$, $$Cov(X,Y)=Cov(X,g(Y)),$$ holds.

Then is it true that $g(Y)$ have to be a linear function of $Y$?

It can be shown easily that if $g$ is linear function then covariance are same. But I am unable to prove the reverse part. Thinking about counter example.

Comment: If $g(y)=aY$ with $a \neq 1$ then the equality does not hold, because the RHS is $aCov(X,Y)$ and $g$ is linear.

Comment: My question is suppose the equality holds for some $g$, then is it true that $g$ have to be linear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not true. First the condition $Cov(X,Y)=Cov(X,g(Y))$ may be written (by the properties of the covariance) as $$Cov(X,Y-g(Y))=0$$ Now, for a (degenerate) counterexample, let $P(Y=1)=1$ and take $g(y)=y^2$. Then $$Cov(X,Y-g(Y))=Cov(X,0)=0$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to find out a counter example in non-generate case?

Comment: Yes. Find a function with more than one fixed points, i.e. points of the form $g(y)=y$. Let $Y$ take values with positive probability only on those fixed points.

Comment: The choice $g(y)=y$, is again linear,  so it `not' a counter example.

Comment: @user23510. For example the function $g(y)=y^2$ has two fixed points $y=0, y=1$ because $g(0)=0^2=0$ and $g(1)=1^2=1$. I did not say that you should take the function $g(y)=y$. Do you see it now?

Comment: I got your points. Thanks.